# Create string templates from arbitrary regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, format, string-formatting

Regular expressions are used to parse already formatted strings but I would like to use them to take raw strings of characters and format them, examples:

```
// phone number
format("\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}", "1234567890");
// should return "(123) 456-7890"
```

```
// date
format("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}", "20180712");
// should return "2018-07-12"
```

```
// arbitrary
format("([A-Z]+-\d+ )+", "ABC123DEFGH45IJ6789");
// should return "ABC-123 DEFGH-45 IJ-6789 "
```

The above are *just examples*, **I'd like a general solution that works for any arbitrary regex and any arbitrary string** (that fits the regex).

Here's what I have so far, which is a little inelegant, and really limited in its abilities, but does satisfy the first 2 of the 3 examples above:

```js
function consumeCharacters(amount) {
  return (characterArray) => {
    return characterArray.splice(0, amount).join('');
  };
}

function parseSimpleRegex(regexString) {
  // filter out backslash escapes
  let parsed = regexString.replace(/\\./g, (...args) => {
    return args[0][args[0].length-1];
  });
  
  // get literal characters
  let literals = parsed.split(/d\{\d\}/);
  
  // get variable symbols
  let variables = parsed.match(/d\{\d\}/g);
  let varFunctions = variables.map(variable => consumeCharacters(variable[2]));
  
  let result = [];
  while (literals.length > 0) {
    result.push(literals.shift());
    result.push(varFunctions.shift());
  }
  while (varFunctions.length > 0) {
    result.push(varFunctions.shift());     
  }
  
  // filter out undefineds & empty strings
  result = result.filter(resultPart => !!resultPart);
  return result;
}

function format(regexString, rawString) {
  let rawCharacters = rawString.split('');
  let formatter = null;
  try {
    formatter = parseSimpleRegex(regexString); 
  } catch (e) {
    return 'failed parsing regex';
  }
  let formattedString = formatter.map((format) => {
    if (typeof format === 'string') {
        return format;
    }
    if (typeof format === 'function') {
        return format(rawCharacters);
    }
  }).join('');
  return formattedString;
}

const testCases = [
  {
    args: ["\\(\\d{3}\\) \\d{3}-\\d{4}", "1234567890"],
    expected: "(123) 456-7890"
  },
  {
    args: ["\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", "20180712"],
    expected: "2018-07-12"
  },
  {
    args: ["([A-Z]+-\\d+ )+", "ABC123DEFGH45IJ6789"],
    expected: "ABC-123 DEFGH-45 IJ-6789 "
  },
];

testCases.forEach((testCase, index) => {
  const result = format(...testCase.args);
  const expected = testCase.expected;
  if (result === expected) {
    console.log(`Test Case #${index+1} passed`);
  } else {
    console.log(`Test Case #${index+1} failed, expected: "${expected}", result: "${result}"`);
  }
});
```

Can the above solution be scaled for more complex regexes? Or is there a better alternative approach?

Comment: For whoever downvoted this question, can you please suggest how I can change it to improve it? Thanks.

Comment: My guess it's because it seems you haven't done anything and ask us to do your job for you -- and that's what the down arrow says, "no research effort".

Comment: My research effort was searching on Google and StackOverflow and finding absolutely nothing, which is what motivated me to ask this question in the first place. I've updated my question with a partial solution to show more effort.

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is: Use a regex that creates `groups`, then use `replace` with backreferences to format the output.

For example, using your first example, use this regex:

```
/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/
```

It creates three Groups, the first 3 numbers, the next 3 numbers and the final 4 numbers.

Now the format, use `string.replace` function:with the following replacement pattern:

```
($1) $2-$3
```

I will add parentheses around the first Group, add a Space, then the second Group and finally a hyphen and the last Group.

**How to use:**

You can create your formatPhone function like this:

```
function formatPhone(rawPhone)
{
    return rawPhone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1) $2-$3');
}
```

You can do similar with your other patterns.

**Edit**:

A totally general soultion requires that you pass, both the raw string, the regex pattern and the replacement pattern to your function, like this:

```
function format(rawString, regex, replacement)
{
   return rawString.replace(regex, replacement);
}
```

where regex and replacement must follow the rules described above.

**Edit2**:

I think you have missunderstood something here. Let's take your first example:

```
format("\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}", "1234567890");
```

Here the regex simply **doesn't match**!!! So in short, you can't make a function that takes a format regex. Regexes are made to `match` (and possibly `replace`) as shown above.

Comment: I appreciate this answer however I don't know ahead of time what the patterns will be, hence why I need a general solution which can take any or almost any regex at runtime and use it to format strings.

Comment: @kfedorov91 could you please revise your question and perhaps add more detail as to why this does not answer your question.

Comment: @SalmanA yes, I've updated my question. PoulBak's answer is insufficient because it doesn't explain how the replacement string would be generated from the regex. Again, the regex could be almost anything. I can't personally handcraft a replacement string for every possible permutation of symbols that forms a valid regex.

Comment: @PoulBak in response to "Edit2" the regex doesn't match the string, yes, but that's the point. I want to use the regex to format the string. As a person you can look at the regex syntax and the raw string and combine them in your head to form a formatted string. You follow an algorithm to do so. I would like to see that algorithm implemented in javascript, or in any language.

Comment: @SalmanA & PoulBak I've updated my answer again with a partial working solution that satisfies 2 of my example cases above. It should make the question much, much clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pattern `(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})` and substitute it with `(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})`, which yields `123-456-7890`.

For third example, use: `(\w{3})(\w{3})(\w{5})(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{4})` and replace it with `\1-\2 \3-\4 \5-\6`, which returns `ABC-123 DEFGH-45 IJ-6789`.

Generally use `(\w{n})...(\w{m})`, where `n` and `m` are some integers for capturing p[arts of a string to parrticular groups (you could specify those intregers with an array). And you could also provide separators in an array as well to form your patterns.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9vMfMa/1)

**UPDATE**

As I said, general solution would be to supply sizes of blocks, that string should be split into and array of separators. See code below:

```
var str =  "ABC123DEFGH45IJ6789";
var blockSizes = [3,3,5,2,2,4];
var separators = ["-"," ","-"," ","-"];
var pattern = "(\\w{" + blockSizes[0] + "})";
var replacementPattern = "$1";
var i;
for(i = 1; i < blockSizes.length; i++)
{
    pattern += "(\\w{" + blockSizes[i] + "})";
    replacementPattern += separators[i - 1] + "$" + (i + 1);
}
```

Now, just use this patterns to replace and you're done:

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ymzhfe5x/)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0TB01k/1)

Comment: Thanks for the question, however I don't know ahead of time what the patterns will be so I can't preemptively create substitution/replacement strings for them. I need a general solution that would work at runtime for any arbitrary regex.